# data-mage-init not working properly

Tags: multi-website, magento2.4, data-mage-init

```
<div class="action toggle switcher-trigger" role="button" tabindex="0" data-mage-init="{&quot;dropdown&quot;:&quot;{}&quot;}" data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger-keypress-button="true" id="switcher-website-trigger">


<div class="action toggle switcher-trigger" role="button" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger-keypress-button="true" id="switcher-website-trigger" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

In the above 2 div,
The first div comes along with raw showing data-mage-init and not processed
while the second div is processed properly

The second div works properly.

whenever the site loads and mostly the site brings like first div case

**Note:** I'm using multi-website

Answer (score 0):

I just ran

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and it worked fine